# Disable writing to nohup.out

Tags: java, unix, log4j, nohup

I am running a java application using the nohup command.

```
nohup java -jar test.jar
```

I am using *log4j* to write output from my application. In the log4j.properties file, I have a file this writes the output. The problem is that I have the same output twice in nohup.out and in test.log(I have configured this in the log4j.properties file)

Is there a way of disabling the writing of the output to nohup.out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redirect nohup output to /dev/null.

```
nohup java -jar test.jar >/dev/null
```

Comment: What does this mean -it is not disable it , it is only redirect it??

Comment: In simple term assume dev/null as black hole. Any thing redirected there will never come back. so it is nearly same as disabling it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device